# Need help decoding Json that contains an array

Tags: json, swift, decode

I need to do the following :
Define two Swift classes to decode the JSON string

Decode the JSON string to get the objects of the two classes

This is the JSON I have to decode :

> {“status":200,"holidays":[{"name":"Thanksgiving","date":"2017-10-09","observed":"2017-10-09","public":false}]}

I have tried creating two classes already and all I get back is nothing when calling the class in the main class

```
class HolidayItems : Decodable {

    let name : String?
    let date : String?
    let observed: String?
    let `public` : Bool?


    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case name
        case date
        case observed
        case `public`

    }

    required init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        date = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .date)
        observed = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .observed)
        `public`  = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .`public`)
    }

    } // HolidayItems

    class HolidayAPI: Decodable {

    let status: HolidayItems

    // let holiday :[HolidayItems]


    func getHolidayName() -> String {
        return status.name ?? "no advice, server problem"
    }
    func getAdviceNo() -> String {
        return status.date ?? ""
    }
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status
        case holiday = "items"
    }

    required init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        status = try container.decode(HolidayItems.self, forKey: .status)
      //  holiday = try container.decode(HolidayItems.self, forKey: .holiday)

    }
}
```

This is the result I'm suppose to get :

> Optional("Thanksgiving")
>   Optional("2017-10-09")

and I get nothing in return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is on root level just object with `status` of type `Int` and one array of another objects

---

**Note**

- you don't have to implement your custom `CodingKey`
- you don't need custom `init` with `Decoder`
- you can have `struct` for your models
- you can rename `HolidayItems` to `Holiday`

```
struct HolidayAPI: Decodable {
    let status: Int
    let holidays: [Holiday]
}

struct Holiday: Decodable {
    let name, date, observed: String
    let `public`: Bool
}
```

Then when you need to get certain holiday item, just get certain element of `holidays`

```
decodedResponse.holidays[0].name
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to have classes and this is how I call it in the main class   
                    self.holiday = try JSONDecoder().decode(HolidayAPI.self, from: self.dataStore as Data)

                        self.holidayTextView.text = self.holiday?.getHolidayName()
                        print(self.holidayTextView.text)

Comment: @newtoSwift but you cant work with your response as with just single object, you receive array of objects

Comment: That worked, thanks. I was working off an example that didn't have an array inside the JSON.